# Why doesn't the text change color when I edit the css page?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-web-developer

I created a new web application in visual web developer. I saw that the title of "Site.Master" (in code) is:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>
        My ASP.NET Application
    </h1>
</div>
```

So I opened "Site.css" and added:

```
h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color:Blue;
}
```

Showing "Default.aspx", though, doesn't show the text ("My ASP.NET Application
") in blue. Why?

**EDIT:** From the source code:

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
```

So I added `color: Blue;` in the css under body, page, header, title, and h1. I rebuilt, and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. Doesn't help. I'm trying this in IE and Firefox.

Comment: Did you refresh the page? I suggest using a tool like Firebug to see the styles applied to the h1.

Comment: Is this really the code you have? color: Blue surrounded by double asterisks? You don't need them here. Do you wanted to lay emphasis (bold)?

Comment: What browser are you using? each one have developer tools that make work a lot easier. In those tools you can select an element, like the title, and it show you what styles are being applied and were they come from.

Comment: @yunzen yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Is the Stylesheet file loaded at all?

Comment: @daniloquio IE9 and Firefox11.

Comment: Press F12 when in IE and you'll see the developer tools. Then, click on the pointer button then, click on the page title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your css like below.

```
.title h1
{ 
    font-size: 1.6em !important; 
    padding-bottom: 0px !important; 
    margin-bottom: 0px !important; 
    color:Blue !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But didn't help. Not even after Rebuild + Ctrl+F5.

Comment: This is overriding style sheet.

Comment: But the css file _is_ the style sheet!

Comment: Evidence is, remove the `!important` from the style and check the output.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. It returns to the old color. (After a Ctrl+F5.)

Comment: So you either have a style tag in your page that overrides your css file, or you have another css file loaded after this one that also overrides it.

Comment: @Tuan Thanks for the input .I discovered it's `.header h1` in the css overriding `h1`. (I think.)

Comment: Using !Important is not recommended http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/ The right way is to handle css's specificity.

Comment: This article does not have strong basis for the same. Even the reply by the users are saying **One Step forward and two step back**

Comment: @PankajGarg using !important is a band-aid. Write your CSS correctly in the first place. I really don't think this is a good answer for best practice.

Comment: Please suggest to improve my code. Fianlly I will definitely ask to unaccept this answer if found a good approach.

Answer (score 6):

The stylesheet is probably cached on the browser.  Clear your browser cache, and you should see the change.

<strike>Also, You probably did this for emphasis, but you don't need to surround the css in asterisks.</strike>

You can prevent this from occurring in the future by appending a query string to the css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='site.css?v=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>' />
```

Something like this will cause the browser to download the css file every time the page is requested.

Comment: @ispiro Then I would ensure that the stylesheet is getting loaded at all.  What browser are you using?  In chrome, you can press F12 to open the developer tools and inspect the styles (elements tab).  You can do similar in IE 8+ as well.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman Thanks. I'm using IE9. F12 doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ispiro Then look for something called "Developer Tools" on the Tools menu.

Answer (score 3):

from: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

> Specificity is calculated by counting various components of your css
>   and expressing them in a form (a,b,c,d). This will be clearer with an
>   example, but first the components.
>
> ```
> Element, Pseudo Element: d = 1 – (0,0,0,1)
> Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: c = 1 – (0,0,1,0)
> Id: b = 1 – (0,1,0,0)
> Inline Style: a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)
> ```

So, the class of div is over-riding the element setting of h1.

Comment: Looks promising. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: See updated question. Also: Pankaj Garg's answer  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9997622/939213) worked. Though I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
color: blue;
```

instead of

```
**color:Blue;**
```

Comment: :) That just showed up that way. I was trying to **Bold** it.

Comment: I think he was just emphatizing that line. He had to be! :D

Comment: Oh, my bad. I hoped it was that way but you can't be sure!

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. It's possible you just need to do a "hard refresh" of the page.  Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and see if that helps.
2. You may need a more specific selector to control that element if another CSS rule is affecting it.  Try changing "`h1`" to "`.title h1`"

Comment: Thanks. But didn't help. Not even after Rebuild + Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @ispiro Ah, gotcha.  Then there must be more to the structure of the page, or more CSS rules affecting this.  I'd take [tuan's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997496/why-doesnt-the-text-change-color-when-i-edit-the-css-page/9997569#comment12778180_9997496) and look in FireBug (or Developer Tools) to see what CSS rules are affecting the h1 text.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why it happens but u need to clean firefox cache and cookie then it works.

Answer (score 0):

This cases are common and almost no solution to this issue (sadly, little can be done) if and only if your web page content was sourced from a template online. To confirm this, create two web forms with different templates and both web forms share the same 'sitemaster' page. it kind of inherits content design.

Comment: There was no need to reopen this question some 6 and a half years after it was asked and already answered. More than that, your input is more fitting in comments to the question than it is fitting the answer form. Try putting more helpful answers on some of still opened questions to get more rep points which will grant you site privilege to post comments.